# How to remove non-launchpad-ppa repository from apt update list?

Tags: apt, package-management

When I run `sudo apt update`, it hits/gets a list of urls, including `Hit:7 http://realsense-hw-public.s3.amazonaws.com/Debian/apt-repo bionic InRelease`.

How do I remove this specific url from what apt updates?

I've found all kinds of ways of removing a known ppa, but I don't have a ppa or launchpad address for this one. It also does not show up in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Here is what shows up for this url in apt policy:

```
500 http://realsense-hw-public.s3.amazonaws.com/Debian/apt-repo bionic/main i386 Packages
     release o=Artifactory,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Artifactory,c=main,b=i386
     origin realsense-hw-public.s3.amazonaws.com
 500 http://realsense-hw-public.s3.amazonaws.com/Debian/apt-repo bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Artifactory,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Artifactory,c=main,b=amd64
     origin realsense-hw-public.s3.amazonaws.com
```

Feel free to correct any mis-used terms.

Comment: Does `grep -r realsense /etc/apt` find anything? (It could be in /etc/apt/sources.list)

Comment: It does! There's two entries each in `list`, `list.save`, and `list.distUpgrade`. I assume those can be deleted using rm, just like I used for other packages in `sources.list.d` ? I'll happily upvote and accept that comment if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `grep -r realsense /etc/apt` to find any files in /etc/apt that include that source. For example, it could be in /etc/apt/sources.list.

apt only processes source list files that end in .list. Any files named .list.save, .list.distUpgrade, and so on are just backups that apt doesn't use.